# Parse JSON into MuliDimensional Array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON file that I would like to create an multi-dimensional array from. This information is stored in a JSON file.

Here is the JSON data.

```
{
  "table": {
    "columnNames": ["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"],
    "columnTypes": ["String", "String", "String", "String"],
    "rows": [
      ["data00", "data01", "data02", "data03"],
      ["data10", "data11", "data12", "data13"],
      ["data20", "data21", "data22", "data23"],
      ["data30", "data31", "data32", "data33"]
     ]
   }
}
```

I need to create an array of arrays from the objects in the "rows" section.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you parse the JSON, the "table.rows" property will already be a multi-dimensional array (2 dimensions, to be specific).  All you have to do is access it:

```
var array2D = parsed.table.rows;
```

As to parsing, you should probably use something like [Crockford's parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js):

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(rawStringOfJSON);
```

Comment: How would I get the rawStringofJSON from a .json file?

Comment: Well, that depends on your server application.  Generally you'd fetch it with some sort of AJAX interaction, but it could be included in a page in other ways.  That probably should be a separate question, as it really doesn't have much to do with the *parsing* aspect of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert the string to JS object.

Use `json2.js` from http://www.json.org/js.html

*Please keep in mind that you need to add json2.js if you consider to support old browsers. Newer browser has built-in support for JSON*

And deserialize the string to object

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext);
```

And now you can access

```
myObject.table.rows[1][2]; // yields data12
```

Answer (score 0):

The rows section already contains an array of arrays, so just use:

```
var result = JSON.parse('{
  "table": {
  "columnNames": ["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"],
  "columnTypes": ["String", "String", "String", "String"],
  "rows": [
    ["data00", "data01", "data02", "data03"],
    ["data10", "data11", "data12", "data13"],
    ["data20", "data21", "data22", "data23"],
    ["data30", "data31", "data32", "data33"]
   ]
  }
}');

var rows = result.table.rows;
```